# Populate dropdown B on the selection of dropdown A, and populate dropdown C on the selection of dropdown B

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fill **Dropdown-B** on the section of **Dropdown-A**, and fill **Dropdown-C** on the selection of **Dropdown-B**.

```js
var mealsByCategory = {

  A: ["fruits", "vegetable", "others"],
  B: ["Apples", "orange", "Grapes"],
  C: ["Carrot", "Ladyfinger", "onions"],
  D: ["Green Apple", "Red Apple"]
}

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="main" id="main" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category" onChange="changecat2(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>

</select>
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>

</select>
```

- If I select dropdown with A option as "fruits", then List B

> B: ["Apples", "orange", "Grapes"]

should be populated in dropdown B.
 - If I select dropdown B with "Apples", then dropdown C should be populated with List D

> D: ["Green Apple", "Red Apple"]

**Fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/k148pk76/171/ 
I am able to fill dropdown list B on the basis of dropdown A, but unable to fill Dropdown C on the selection of Dropdown B.
Please help!

Comment: Can you create a code snippet so we can debug with working version

Comment: @DarrenSweeney :Above code snippet is in working state .

Comment: Fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/k148pk76/171/

Comment: There's no function called `changecat2` so this isn't working code - Look at the console errors, this is basic debugging

Comment: That's what, how to write method for third dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Added changecat2() method for the third dropdown and updated changecat() method for third dropdown, just try the below code.

```js
var mealsByCategory = {
  Fruits: ["Apples", "Orange", "Grapes"],
  Vegetables: ["Carrot", "Ladyfinger", "onions"],
  Apples: ["Green Apple", "Red Apple"],
  Orange: ["Green Orange", "Orange"],
  Grapes: ["Green Grapes", "Black Grapes"]
}

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (var categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
debugger;
    var subCatOptions = "";
    var selectedInCategory = document.getElementById('category').selectedOptions[0].textContent;
    for (var subCategoryId in mealsByCategory[selectedInCategory]) {
      subCatOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[selectedInCategory][subCategoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML = subCatOptions;
  }
}

function changecat2(value) {
  debugger;
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var subCatOptions = "";
    for (var subCategoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      subCatOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][subCategoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML = subCatOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="main" id="main" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category" onChange="changecat2(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>

</select>
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>

</select>
```